# how to get unkown root tag parse to function

Tags: perl, xml-twig

i doing xml conversion, here i define root tag as book, but how to get unknow root tag define here, i need common syntex,

```
use twig;

my $story_file = XML::Twig->new(
                                   twig_handlers =>{
                                            'book' => \&book,
                                            keep_atts_order => 1,
                                            },
                                            pretty_print => 'indented',
                                  );

$story_file->parsefile('unknown.xml');
$story_file->print($out);
```

i tried,

```
use twig;

my $story_file = XML::Twig->new(
                                   twig_handlers =>{
                                            root => \&book,
                                            keep_atts_order => 1,
                                            },
                                            pretty_print => 'indented',
                                  );

$story_file->parsefile('unknown.xml');
$story_file->print($out);
```

It did't work, if any comman syntex for root tag, plase with examples

Comment: It's not work becuase am not using xpath option sir,

Answer (score 1):

The keys of twig_handlers are XPaths, so you can use `/*`.

```
use XML::Twig;

sub root { print "root\n"; }

my $story_file = XML::Twig->new(
   twig_handlers =>{
      '/*' => \&root,
   },
   keep_atts_order => 1,
   pretty_print    => 'indented',
);

$story_file->parsefile('unknown.xml');
$story_file->print($out);
```

I have 3.41 installed.

Comment: I tried this script, i got some error: (unrecognized expression in handler: '/*' at sample.pl line 5)

Comment: weird, it works for me. Do you have an old version of XML::Twig? You could also use `level(0)` as the trigger (introduced in XML::Twig 3.16, released in February 2005)

Comment: am currently using XML::Twig 3.26 module

Comment: How to get XML-Twig 3.16 module through ppm

Comment: 3.26 is more recent than 3.16, so `level(0)` should work. 3.26 is 6 years old (June 2008) though, I see that Activestate has ppm for version 3.34/3.40, depending on the platform, so it might be a good idea to upgrade if you can.

Comment: please give if any link exactly for this?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-Twig/ is the first link returned by a google search on `XML::Twig ppm`. Sometimes it's quicker to try by yourself than ask someone who might be busy with their own job.